# SQL - create new column based on the one-to-one or one-to-many relationship between two original columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with the fields `id`, `name`, and `type`. An `id` can be linked to one or two names or no names. If an `id` is linked to two names, the `type` for each of the names can be `red` or `blue` but they cannot be both `blue` or both `red` like below.

```
id  name  type   
1   null  null
2   ai3   red
3   wz2   blue
4   5ef   blue
4   l2e   red
```

If an `id` does have two names attached to it I want to create a new category called `both`. I'm not sure how to use a CASE statement to accomplish this.

```
id  name  type cat   
1   null  null null
2   ai3   red  red
3   wz2   blue blue
4   5ef   blue both
4   l2e   red  both
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(type) over (partition by id) <> max(type) over (partition by id)
             then 'both'
             else min(type) over (partition by id)
        end) as cat
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this may work, may need to be tweaked but that's the way most `CASE` statements work:

```
 ALTER TABLE t2
 ADD `cat` as (CASE WHEN t2.type = 'Blue' Then 'Blue'
                 WHEN t2.type = 'Blue' AND t2.type = 'Red' Then 'both'
                 WHEN t2.type = 'Red' Then 'Red'
            END)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get around using UPDATE? I was able to find a janky solution using tableau of all things but would prefer to use SQL haha

Comment: I doubt it, since `UPDATE` is used for only updating current database records, so like you could probably update your current table with new data but not for adding another column.

Comment: Your case expression will never return `'both'` because the condition `t2.type = 'Blue' AND t2.type = 'Red'` is always false